# How to add a picture in widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

Please tell me, how to add a picture in widget.TextInputLayout?
Here in this place...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rfJF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that built into `TextInputLayout`. That space is reserved for the character counter, as seen in this image:

[image]

This counter can be enabled with the attributes `app:counterEnabled` and `app:counterMaxLength`, but these are text, not images.

You could perhaps wrap your `TextInputLayout` with a `FrameLayout` and add an `ImageView` with `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is a counter there, try to do as you have said, thank you.